# Is there any point in using both rifle and pistol?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm currenlty playing a sneaky sniper. I'm level 27 and have been experimenting around what kind of weapon loadout I should use.

Currently my "main" weapon is a sniper rifle (of some sort) for long distance and a rifle for medium to close encounters. For RP-value I've also used pistols, primarily when fighting indoors. So basically, I have three types of weapons: sniper, assault rifle and a pistol. RP aside, it just seems rather redundant to have a pistol even for very close battles when my current rifle (All American) seems doing the job just fine for those moments when a sniper rifle isn't really viable.

So basically: Is there really any point in having both a pistol and a rifle for closer fighting?

Comment: pistols use a lot less AP typically in VATS mode

Comment: Well, I think All American uses pretty few AP's as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pistol?  Rifle?  Why not both!  [That Gun](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/That_Gun) is my sidearm of choice, and it fires a rifle round, which means your ammo can be shared between your pistol and your rifle.  It does very good damage even into the mid- and late-game.

However, one advantage to multiple weapon types is fully using your available ammunition.  You'll come across many different types of ammo, and sometimes you might be low on 5.56.  Having a backup weapon that fires something else might be good in these cases.

Another thing to consider is if you want a sidearm that has a silencer.  I like [Sleepytyme](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sleepytyme_(GRA)) for this, which is a SMG that fires 10mm rounds.  It does decent damage and the silencer means I can stay sneaky even in close quarters.  There are pistol-type options available with a silencer if you're hell-bent on using a pistol.

Rifles are also not [holdout weapons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Fallout:_New_Vegas_holdout_weapons), which means you can't take them into casinos and other "weapon restricted" areas.  Many 1-handed weapons (including Sleepytyme, but not That Gun) are holdout weapons, though.

If you're happy with the All American, and none of these concerns apply to you, then I don't really see any other need to carry another close-quarters weapon.

Comment: sleepytyme is by far my favorite gun for close up situations.  Nice AP cost in VATS, silence, great damage, and abundant ammo

Comment: The only thing I feel is that when everything goes haywire, an autofiring weapon seem better when the enemy is in your face.

Comment: @Sandokan, Sleepytyme is good for this, although That Gun will *wreck face* so fast you won't really have to worry about most enemies, tbh.  (Your mileage may vary, depending on difficulty, etc).  When I draw it and go into VATS, it's a safe assumption that whatever I'm shooting at is probably going to be dead by the time I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have as many different guns as I can hold, while remaining a safe distance under my max-weight as possible. The variety of ammunition, which is weightless, means that should I run out of ammo, I can just switch guns.

Comment: Unless of course, you're playing on Hardcore mode, in which case, carrying all that spare ammo is kind of a drag, man.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz This is, admittedly, true.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, real-life military snipers use both. We have our sniper rife for long-distance targets, and our emergency sidearm in case we're surprised in our "nest." When moving into position, keep a handgun or shotgun equipped in case you're surprised by something around a corner.

Comment: Actually it depends. For the "stereotypical" sniper it may very well be so. But many ordinary infantry rifle squads have a sniper with them, a dedicated marksman. He is really just a soldier who has recieved sniper training. He is most often armed with a sniper rifle and a regular assault rifle.